# Playing videos using textureview inside recyclerview with cardview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-textureview

I done video playing inside recyclerview with cardview using sdcard path location. Also check sdcard not available then fetch recorded videos from internal memory. Its perfectly working in Lava iris x8 device, but in Samsung J5 and Samsung Note 2 only odd numbers(1,3,5,7) videos are playing not even(2,4,6,8) videos are playing and getting dialog like "Can't play this video" when scrolling and getting position of even(2,4,6,8) numbers of video. I am not able to know what is the problem? Below is my whole code about display and play video inside recyclerview and cardview in android.

display_video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mRelative_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#6FC298">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mRelativeClick"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="left">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImage_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/icon_back"></ImageView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="My Challenge"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_setting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/icon_setting"></ImageView>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mRelative_circular_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_color1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/color1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_color2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mImageView_color1"
                android:src="@mipmap/color2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_color3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mImageView_color2"
                android:src="@mipmap/color3"/>

            <app.stakes.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/mcircularImage"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/camera_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_color4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mcircularImage"
                android:src="@mipmap/color4"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_color5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mImageView_color4"
                android:src="@mipmap/color5"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_color6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mImageView_color5"
                android:src="@mipmap/color6"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextViewUsername_VideoList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mRelative_circular_image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageView_color_table"
            android:src="@mipmap/color_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mRelative_circular_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mRelativeTab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mRelative_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageViewtab2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/list"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageViewtab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageViewtab3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/showbook"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/mRelativeTab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

cardview1.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/mRelativeMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconId"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>-->

        <app.stakes.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImageview"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/camera_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersionName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circleImageview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Auther"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="7sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/circleImageview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mImageview_clock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvSec"
            android:src="@mipmap/timing"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSec"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="Lollipop"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="5sp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/video_frame"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/circleImageview">

            <com.sprylab.android.widget.TextureVideoView
                android:id="@+id/mvideoView"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                 />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mImageview_play"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:src="@mipmap/play" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/mImageView_fav"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mImageview_play"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/bookmark_video" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mImageView_share"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mImageview_play"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/sharevideo" />
                <!--</RelativeLayout>-->
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Display_Video1.java

```
public class Display_Video1 extends ActionBarActivity {
public RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<FeddProperties> os_versions;
private Adapter mAdapter;
private Adapter fav_video_adapter;
CircularImageView mcircularImage;
static DisplayMetrics dm;
static MediaController media_Controller;
RelativeLayout mRelativeClick;
static boolean isViewWithCatalog;
RelativeLayout mRelative_background;
static File OldFile;
static String[] fileList = null;
static String[] fileListOld = null;
/*static String FILE_PATH = newFile.getAbsolutePath();*/
static String FILEPATH_OLD;
static String videoOldFilePath;
static String replaceOldString;
String MiME_TYPE = "video/mp4";
static String videoFilePath;
static String replaceStr;
static String[] fav_video_list = null;

CallbackManager callbackManager;
public static String facebook_user_id;
public static String username;
Boolean isSDPresent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.display_video);

    isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    if(isSDPresent) {
        OldFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Stakes_Download");
        MEDIA_PATHOLD =  new String(OldFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FILEPATH_OLD = OldFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    else{
        OldFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "Stakes_Download");
        MEDIA_PATHOLD =  new String(OldFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FILEPATH_OLD = OldFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }


   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            os_versions = new ArrayList<FeddProperties>();
            if (fileList != null) {


                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                    if (fileList[i].length() == 0) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        alist.add(fileList.length);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Zero: " + Arrays.toString(fileList), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }

            if (fileListOld != null) {


                for (int i = 0; i < fileListOld.length; i++) {
                    if (fileListOld[i].length() == 0) {
                        ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        alist.add(fileListOld.length);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Zero: " + Arrays.toString(fileListOld), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }

            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            // ListView
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Display_Video1.this));


            // create an Object for Adapter
            if (fileList != null) {
                mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(Display_Video1.this, fileList);
                // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            } else {
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No File Exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
            }

    updateSongList();
    updateSongListOld();
    initContrls();
}

public void updateSongList() {

    File videoFiles = new File(MEDIA_PATHOLD);
    Log.d("**Value of videoFiles**", videoFiles.toString());

    if (videoFiles.isDirectory()) {
        fileList = videoFiles.list();
    }
    if (fileList == null) {
        System.out.println("File doesnot exit");
        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        System.out.println("fileList****************" + fileList);
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            Log.e("Video:" + i + " File name", fileList[i]);

        }
    }
}

public void updateSongListOld() {

    File videoFiles = new File(MEDIA_PATHOLD);
    Log.d("**Value of videoFiles**", videoFiles.toString());

    if (videoFiles.isDirectory()) {
        fileListOld = videoFiles.list();
    }
    if (fileListOld == null) {
        System.out.println("File doesnot exit");
        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        System.out.println("fileList****************" + fileListOld);
        for (int i = 0; i < fileListOld.length; i++) {
            Log.e("Video:" + i + " File name", fileListOld[i]);

        }
    }
}

private void initContrls() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    os_versions = new ArrayList<FeddProperties>();
    if (fileList != null) {
        /*gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, fileList));*/


        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            if (fileList[i].length() == 0) {
                ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                alist.add(fileList.length);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Zero: " + Arrays.toString(fileList), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               /* FeddProperties feed = new FeddProperties();

                feed.setTitle(fileList[i]);
                *//*feed.setThumbnail(icons[i]);*//*
                os_versions.add(feed);*/
            }
        }
    }

    if (fileListOld != null) {
        /*gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, fileList));*/


        for (int i = 0; i < fileListOld.length; i++) {
            if (fileListOld[i].length() == 0) {
                ArrayList<Integer> alist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                alist.add(fileListOld.length);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Zero: " + Arrays.toString(fileListOld), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               /* FeddProperties feed = new FeddProperties();

                feed.setTitle(fileList[i]);
                *//*feed.setThumbnail(icons[i]);*//*
                os_versions.add(feed);*/
            }
        }
    }

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // ListView
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //Grid View
    /* recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,1,false));*/

    //StaggeredGridView
     /*recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1));*/

    // create an Object for Adapter
    if (fileList != null) {
        mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(Display_Video1.this, fileList);
        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No File Exist",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    }


    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new CardViewDataAdapter(Display_Video1.this, new CardViewDataAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
}
```

Recyclerview Adapter

```
public static class CardViewDataAdapter extends Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> implements OnItemTouchListener {
        private ArrayList<FeddProperties> dataSet;
        private OnItemClickListener mListener;
        GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
        private Context context;
        private String[] VideoValues;
        private int position = 0;
        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
        }
        public CardViewDataAdapter(Context context, String[] VideoValues) {

            /*dataSet = os_versions;*/
            this.context = context;
            this.VideoValues = VideoValues;
        }
        public CardViewDataAdapter(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {

            mListener = listener;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            // create a new view
            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.card_view1, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
            videoFilePath = FILEPATH_OLD + "/" + fileList[i];
            Toast.makeText(context,"Path: "+videoFilePath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            viewHolder.tvVersionName.setText(fileList[i]);
            System.out
                    .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> file path>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                            + fileList[i]);

            viewHolder.mvideoView.setVideoPath(videoFilePath);
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(videoFilePath));
            final String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            long timeInMillisec = Long.parseLong(time);
            final long duration = timeInMillisec / 1000;
            long hours = duration / 3600;
            long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
            final long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);
            viewHolder.tvSec.setText(String.valueOf(seconds) + "s");

            viewHolder.mImageview_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (viewHolder.mvideoView!= null) {



                        if (viewHolder.mvideoView.isPlaying()) {
                            viewHolder.mvideoView.pause();
                            viewHolder.mImageview_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play);

                        } else {
                            viewHolder.mvideoView.start();
                            viewHolder.mImageview_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play_click);
                        }

                    }
                    viewHolder.mvideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            viewHolder.mImageview_play.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


            viewHolder.str = fileList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return VideoValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                mListener.onItemClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

        }

        // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView tvVersionName;
            public TextView tvTitle;
            public TextView tvSec;
            /*public ImageView iconView;*/
            /*public RelativeLayout mvideoView;*/
            public TextureVideoView mvideoView;
            public ImageView mImageview_play;
            public CircularImageView circleImageview;
            public ImageView mImageView_fav;
            public ImageView mImageView_share;


            public FeddProperties feed;
            public String[] str;

            public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
                super(itemLayoutView);

                tvVersionName = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvVersionName);
                /*iconView = (ImageView) itemLayoutView
                        .findViewById(R.id.iconId);*/

                tvSec = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvSec);
                tvTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                mvideoView = (TextureVideoView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.mvideoView);

                mImageview_play = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.mImageview_play);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?